# How to develop a file uploader control similar to the one in live skydrive using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, onedrive

I like the drag & drop feature of the skydrive file upload control. How do i go about developing a similar control?

Answer (score 0):

C# will only assist you at the sever side of this feature, most of it uses Java Script (client side) to upload the files in a pretty AJAX way (very similar to GMail attachments). You can use the [following example](http://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress/tree/master) to implement something similar to Skydrive's.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) can assist you of implementing the asynchronous upload part.

Answer (score 0):

check my source code if it's useful

```
using System;
using System.Data.ProviderBase;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (fileupload.HasFile)
try {

    fileupload.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\" + fileupload.FileName);
lbl.Text = "File name: " +
fileupload.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
fileupload.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
"Content type: " +
fileupload.PostedFile.ContentType;  
}
catch (Exception ex) {
lbl.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString(); 
}
else
{
lbl.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
} 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="fileupload.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" runat="server">

<asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="upload" Text="Upload" runat="server" onclick="upload_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SilverLight solution I found:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SL4-Desktop-Drag-and-Drop-Silver-Sky.aspx